# Wordpress CSS image autoresponsive

Tags: css, wordpress

The following image demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish.

The A) it's on webbrowser of computer, which displays cool. The B) it's on mobile devices or small screens. I would like to make the images appear on mobile devices like the A).

[image]

I'm attempting this on Wordpress in the header.php. I've been searching and I've got this:

```
<a href="http://url">
<img src="http://urlIMAGE" width="100px" height="95px" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto;"/></a>
<a href="url" target="_blank">
<img src="http://urlIMAGE" width="100px" height="95px" style="max-width: auto; height: auto;"/></a>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: *sidenote:* there is no `px` in `width` or `height` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some thing like:

```
float: left;
```

or

```
float: right;
```

inside your style attribute. See if that works.

Answer (score 3):

```
a img{width:100%; float:left;}
```